# How to integrate a chatbot webhook with a web-based chat window?

Tags: javascript, css, chat, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I want to develop a web-based chat conversation. I have a Dialogflow webhook that is up and running and that can be easily integrated with, say, facebook messenger or whatsapp, thanks to the functionalities of Dialogflow itself.

Now, say I want to have a web-based chat plugin that I want to interact with said Dialogflow webhook. How does that work, in terms of setup? There are things I know I need, I would like your help to identify things that are still missing and to help me put them all together (conceptually).

- I need something to make the chat conversation look pretty; I was hoping there would be some chat plugin online to style messages but the things I could find are always more complicated than that and have functionalities for you to set messages for the plugin to send automatically and things like that.
- I need *something* that is triggered when the user sends a message; when the user sends a message I need to send it to Dialogflow in order to have it fulfilled. Can this be done directly from JS? Or do I have to send some request to my server, which will then call Dialogflow and return the user message?

Is this all I need? I am sorry if this question is too confusing or broad, I'll be glad to give further clarifications as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this.

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api#detect-intent-text-nodejs

When you use the API for interactions, your service interacts directly with the end-user. For each conversational turn, your service sends end-user expressions to Dialogflow by calling the `detectIntent` or `streamingDetectIntent` method of the `Sessions` type. Dialogflow responds with information about the matched intent, the action, the parameters, and the response defined for the intent. Your service performs actions as needed (for example, database queries or external API calls) and sends a message to the end-user.

It just API interaction with your chat client, you can design the way you want.